# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, image-processing

```
def convert_to_grayscale(self):
    subdirectories = self.list_subdirectories()

    for subdirectory_name in subdirectories:
        subdirectory_path = os.path.join(self.base_dir, subdirectory_name)
        image_files = [os.path.join(subdirectory_path, file) for file in os.listdir(subdirectory_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(subdirectory_path, file))]

        if image_files:
            for image_path in image_files:
                img = image.load_img(image_path)
                img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
                img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # Ensure it's 3-channel
                cv2.imwrite(image_path, img_gray)

    print("Grayscale conversion and saving completed.")
```

while calling this :
`image_processing.convert_to_grayscale()`

I got this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-feb64db6939a> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 image_processing.convert_to_grayscale()

<ipython-input-27-7a06c7c14fb3> in convert_to_grayscale(self)
     52             for image_path in image_files:
     53                 img = image.load_img(image_path)
---> 54                 if len(image.shape) == 3 and image.shape[2] == 3:
     55                     img = cv2.cvtColor(image.img_to_array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     56 

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'shape'
```

Solution of this I try different ways and I also used chatgpt but didn't got the right answer.

Comment: Replace `image.shape` with `img.shape`. `img` is your image loaded by `image.load_img(...)`. Your code is not what appears in the exception!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `image.shape` by `img.shape`:

```
     52             for image_path in image_files:
     53                 img = image.load_img(image_path)
---> 54                 if len(image.shape) == 3 and image.shape[2] == 3:
     55                     img = cv2.cvtColor(image.img_to_array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Replace:

```
if len(image.shape) == 3 and image.shape[2] == 3:
```

With:

```
if len(img.shape) == 3 and img.shape[2] == 3:
```

However, if `img` is a PIL Image, you can check `mode` attribute:

```
if img.mode == 'RGB':
    img = cv2.cvtColor(...)
```

Comment: Did you import `keras.utils` as `image` like: `import keras.utils as image`?